# Xero API - Invoice URL link to a source - change button text?

Tags: xero-api, n8n

I'm using an [n8n](https://n8n.io/) workflow to [create an invoice using the Xero API](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/invoices/#post-invoices), triggered by new Shopify orders.

The API allows me to set a `Url` parameter to utilise:

> URL link to a source document – shown as "Go to [appName]" in the Xero app
> [image]

However, despite the link provided pointing to Shopify, because the API call is made by n8n, "Go to n8n" is displayed in the button.

Is there any way to amend this to "Go to Shopify"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change it is to rename the app name from "n8n" to "Shopify"

Note: Shopify is a certified integration in Xero App Store thus you cannot re-use the name. One option is to add something unique to you e.g. Joe's Shopify